# trying to get number of seconds from the epoch to the day, using %s, getting invalid date

Tags: linux, date

When I'm trying to run the below command, I'm getting correct output

```
date --date="04/1/2022 7:1:00" +'%s'

output: 1648776660
```

But when trying to run the same command with a different date, 29 Jan 2022, it says invalid date:

```
 date --date="29/1/2022 7:1:00" +'%s'

 error:   date: invalid date ‘29/1/2022 7:1:00’
```

Is it due to the first part being considered a month? In that case how to handle `%s`?

as its considering 29th as a month and getting invalid date. Is there any way i can transform from dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss to any other date format so that i can add %s and get the seconds ? Pls any suggestion

Comment: Probably related questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy+date

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @IsaaC .. Thanks for the reply. Its Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Is it possible for you to transform dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd?  This is the unambiguous ISO 8601 format and is accepted by `date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default input format for (GNU) `date` is the e-mail date format (Please read [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)). That format was initially defined in [RFC-822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) as `dd mmm yy`. But `mmm` means the 3 letters (English) month name. As an extension, most `date` programs also accept numeric `mm/dd/yyyy`  (with month first). [Similar to what's defined in POSIX date: `mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/date.html)

In Ubuntu (your OS) the default `date` is GNU date, which expect the `mm/dd/yyy` format. There is no current way (GNU coreutils 8.32) to define other formats.

You can use `-D` available in busybox date to parse a generic format:
Install busybox with `sudo apt-get install busybox` (after `sudo apt-get update -y`) in Ubuntu.

```
$ busybox date -D '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' --date='04/1/2022 7:1:00'
Tue Jan  4 07:01:00 IST 2022
```

Assuming you are in India (IST time or +5:30).

Of course, specifying an output format of `+'%s'` will give you the seconds since epoch. Beware that that will give you the time at IST, not UTC.

```
$ busybox date -D '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' --date='04/1/2022 7:1:00 +0530' +'%s'
1641259860

$ date -ud @1641259860
Tue 04 Jan 2022 01:31:00 AM UTC
```

Note how times are different !!.

For everyone else (not in India time) that result could be reproduced with:

```
$ TZ='Asia/Kolkata' busybox date -D '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' --date='04/1/2022 7:1:00' +'%s'
1641259860
```

In some BSD date implementations we can use the `-j` and `-f` options for [similar results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348963/how-to-convert-date-string-to-epoch-timestamp-with-the-os-x-bsd-date-command).

```
$ date -j -f "%d/%m/%Y %T" "04/1/2022 7:1:00" +"%s"
1641259860
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `+%s`. Are you sure `date` can parse `dd/mm/yyyy` format ?

(man page makes no provision to set a `LC_TIME`value).

In your epoch sample above

```
LC_TIME=C date -d@1648776660
Fri Apr  1 03:31:00 CEST 2022
```

were you testing for Jan 4th or Apr 1st? (and time does not match 7:1:00)

My guess is that `29/1/2022` is parsed as the 29th month's 1st day of 2022.

---

Edit: confirmed using `--debug` option

```
$ date --debug --date="29/01/2022 7:1:00" +'%s'

date: warning: value 29 has less than 4 digits. Assuming MM/DD/YY[YY]
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2022-29-01
date: parsed time part: 07:01:00
date: input timezone: system default
date: using specified time as starting value: '07:01:00'
date: error: invalid date/time value:
date:     user provided time: '(Y-M-D) 2022-29-01 07:01:00'
date:        normalized time: '(Y-M-D) 2024-05-01 07:01:00'
date:                                  ---- --
date:      possible reasons:
date:        numeric values overflow;
date:        missing timezone
date: invalid date ‘29/01/2022 7:1:00’
```

Comment: Yes your guess is correct. It considering it as 29th Month but not as 29th January. Is there a way we can parse %s with dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: I am testing it for 4th January but not April 1st

Comment: Is there any way i can convert this timestamp to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss and then do %s ?

Comment: @Arya There is no indication in your question that you are locked into using dates on that particular format.  If your question is actually about transforming the given date strings to something that GNU `date` can parse, then this should probably be part of the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda . Thank You. I just added more details in the question.